# HTML vs HTML5 & CSS vs CSS3?

Tags: html, css

I have an assignment which requires that I make a website and I have to decide between HTML+CSS and HTML5+CSS3, which I am unclear what the difference is, or which is easier.

Could you please answer the following :

Which is easier:

- *HTML* or *HTML5* ?
- *CSS* or *CSS3*

Can I combine HTML with CSS ?

Can I combine HTML5 with CSS ?

Comment: This is not a proper question for this community Arigoh. You can google and learn most of that stuff and please check help documents on how to ask a question.

Comment: I just want to ask it to the programmer or coder here, because they have experience @GandalftheWhite

Comment: I get your point mate but that is not how this community works. And I'd suggest you to learn both things, if you are serious about the subject then learn as much as possible and in the end it'll help you.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I received it well :) @GandalftheWhite

Comment: Best of luck mate.

Comment: can i have you social media contact for asking a question directly to you? :) @GandalftheWhite

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**More simple HTML or HTML5?**

The syntax is essentially the same except for minor differences. Usually, HTML5 is referred to as HTML. Browsers interpret every HTML document, if not specified otherwise by the document, as HTML5. You can read more about standards on W3.org, https://www.w3.org/standards/

**More simple CSS or CSS3?**

There is no difference between syntax in CSS and CSS3. CSS3 has more features, such as rounded corners and a few more psuedo selectors.

**can i combining HTML with CSS(not CSS3) ?**

Yes, that's the point of it. CSS is used for adding style to the markup, which is HTML.

**can i combining HTML5 with CSS ?**

Yes, that's the point of it.